# How to use into out file in an external server

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to use into out file mysql query inside an external host .

my query is like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT 'Name', 'Email', 'Type of inquiry' , 'Message'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT `engine4_mytbl_contacts`.name ,
        `engine4_mytbl_contacts`.email, 
        `engine4_mytbl_contacts`.topic,
        `engine4_mytbl_contacts`.feed_back
        FROM engine4_mytbl_contacts WHERE contact_date >= '$prevDate' into outfile '$path' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','   ENCLOSED BY '\"'  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n\r'";
```

it's working fine in my local host.
Now I am trying to use that in an external host . My account privilege don't have file permission grant . And I am unable to grant it. Now how can I use this query. Or is there any solution for me ? I mean any alternative way .

Comment: If you don't have permission to access the file system then no, you cannot use that feature. That is exactly what that option is about.

Comment: Question is why you have to do that on that system itself. Why can't you simply run the query using any client or scripting language on that system or another that has access to that mysql server and then dump whatever data you are interested in from that situation?

Comment: I am trying to run the query to grant file access and the query throwing error

Comment: Well, most likely you do not have permission to alter permissions? That would not be unexpected if that is not your own system.

Comment: thanks for your reply. so what can I do . is there any other way to do this?

Comment: I already answered to that in my second comment above.

Comment: Hi, I need do this into one of my projects, as @arkascha correcly said it is not possible to do, but it doesn't mean that have no workaround. Into my project I solve my needs, mounting on the externel server a nfs partition of database server, that way mysql doesn't complaing because the file was not on remote server.

Comment: my database is managed by some third party . I have just phpmyadmin . so is there any way for it ?

Comment: I ma using amazon rds